# Rails: How do i validate two columns for same combination of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table name Conversation with columns initiator_id and member_id, now the validation should check for combinations like

```
Conversation.create(initiator_id: 1, member_id: 2) ---> should create successfully

Conversation.create(initiator_id: 2, member_id: 1) ---> should throw error
```

The validation I'm looking for is 'Conversation should not have the same two set of users'

Is it better to just create a custom validator?? or is there any other alternative?

Comment: From the info given, it is a bit difficult to understand why these would throw an error. It would help if you explain what kind of validation you are trying to achieve

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Hey! so it woudnt throw an error by default, i want to validate it accordingly, thats the point. The validation im looking for is 'Conversation should not have the same two set of users'

Comment: The intent of the validation is missing in the question. The comment clarifies it. 
Custom validators is the easiest to implement and maintain in this case. Is there a reason why you don't want to use custom validators?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous No reason not to use custom validation. Just wanted to know the possible alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least one custom validator.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord

  validates :initiator, uniqueness: { scope: :member, 
    message: 'conversation between these two exists'}

  validate :check_initiator_vs_member

  private

  def check_initiator_vs_member
    return unless self.class.find_by(initiator: member, member: initiator)
    
    errors.add(:initiator, 'conversation between these two exists')
  end
end
```